# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - hidding the row in a grid after delete without reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have successfully implemented a delete function based on the row user select.  The delete calls the server in ajax, so in order to reflect the changes, once the delete operation ends successfully, I call the famous trigger("reloadGrid").

De-facto, the only reason I call "reloadGrid" is for the "removal" of that line that was deleted, so I was thinking, if there is a way to "hide" the deleted line without calling the reload function?

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: i think the only way you can do this by hiding element from dom using jquery/javascript. if you are using `dataType:local` then operaton will be performaed at client side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the row will be deleted using `delGridRow` method. The method will be used if the user click on Delete button of `navGrid` or on Delete button of `formatter: "actions"`. The method have the option `reloadAfterSubmit` which default value is `true`. If you would set it to `false` then the row will be deleted on the server **and locally**. In case of usage free jqGrid one can just add the option

```js
formDeleting: { reloadAfterSubmit: false }
```

It will change the default behavior of `delGridRow` method for the grid.

The disadvantages of the approach:

- the current page can have less then maximal rows. For example if you had `rowNum: 20` on the page (which could be not the last one), then it will be displayed only 19 rows on the page. In the most cases it's not a real problem. The user can press of the next/previous page button or on Reload grid to have full page.
- it can be that other users work with the same data from the other computer. In the case you can have differences between the rows displayed in the grid and on the backend. Reloading of the grid makes the state of grid actual. So you should decide depend on your exact requirements whether reloading of the grid is important or not.